# Why is .each only going through the first element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote this method:

```
def create_demo_organizations

  sample_organizations = [ '37 Signals', 'Fog Creek']

  sample_organizations.each { |item|
    Organization.first_or_create(
        name: item,
        time_zone: 'Central'
    )
  }

end
```

I was hoping it would create two organizations with the names in the array for me, but when I opened it in a UI Admin tool I can only see the first row which is for '37 signals' and not the second row. Did I write it wrong?

My goal was to iterate through members of that array and insert them in the database.

Comment: Try tailing your log/development.log file... what database queries do you see executed when that method is run?

Comment: not sure how to do all those but this method is part of a Rake task that populates the database, when I run the rake task it shows nothing new...just runs the command and goes to next line... in the log of DB? I don't know, I open another terminal and run PostgreSQL ... in that one I don't see much either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First try to isolate the active record code from the loop code. So start with:

```
sample_organizations.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

If you're getting both items printed, add a simpler AR call:

```
sample_organizations.each do |item|
  Organization.create(name: item)
end
```

Then finally:

```
sample_organizations.each do |item|
  Organization.find_or_create(name: item)
end
```

**EDIT:**

I don't think you're calling `first_or_create` correctly. You probably want something like this:

```
Organization.where(name: item).where(time_zone: 'Central').first_or_create
```

Comment: hmm yep your new WHERE command worked,  what's the difference between the way I had written it and your way?

Comment: Mine is calling `first_or_create` on an ActiveRecord::Relation. Yours is attempting it on your class itself (which is NOT a relation).